# DC compatible DNS Server?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

Is there an alternative DNS server that would work with a Windows Server 2008R2 Domain Controller?

I would like to have a DNS server but it seems overkill having a complete install of Windows Server 2008R2 just for the sake of the DNS server.

When I say 'work with' I mean it would join the Windows domain.

Comment: Sorry, that makes no sense. DNS Servers do not "join the domain", the operating system they are installed upon handles that.

Why not just install the DNS role on the domain controller you already have? That's common practice in this kind of situation.

Comment: I knew I wasn't understanding it correctly! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that you only have one domain controller today, and therefore only one DNS server. The advice that any experienced admin would give you is to set up a second DC (with Global Catalog), wich implies DNS.

Having a second DNS server doesnt help you squat if the only DC is dead.

Comment: So if I have two DC's give them both DNS roles and use one as primary and one as secondary?

Comment: They require the DNS role, it gets installed automatically once you promote a server to a DC.